# The SOAPBody content cannot be extracted if more than 1 child element exists

Tags: java, soap, weblogic, multipart, saaj

I'm trying to read a SOAP response (content-type multipart/mixed.  Mime headers: application/soap+xml)
This is working for us in Java 1.6 and Weblogic 11g, but not in Java 1.7/Weblogic 12c.  The extractContentAsDocument() that throws the exception is coming from: jar:file:/u01/app/oracle/Middleware/12c/oracle_common/modules/com.oracle.webservices.orasaaj-rt-api_12.1.2.jar!/oracle/j2ee/ws/saaj/soap/soap12/Body12.class

Error:

javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: The SOAPBody content cannot be extracted if more than 1 child element exists
                    at oracle.j2ee.ws.saaj.soap.BodyImpl.extractContentAsDocument(BodyImpl.java:233)
                    at queryProducer(queryProducer.java:84)

```
queryProducer.java:83:

SOAPMessage response = dispatch.invoke(request);
return response.getSOAPBody().extractContentAsDocument();
```

full response (as a string):

urn:ihe:iti:2007:CrossGatewayQueryResponse
    f3116ff8-378d-11e4-b68e-8f828f8a95e9
    urn:ihe:iti:2007:CrossGatewayQuery

```
      <AdhocQueryResponse xmlns="urn:mynamespace" status="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:ResponseStatusType:Success">
```

...

Maven Dependency Tree:

```
[INFO] mypackage.myapp:myapp_wrap_haims_query:war:4.4.1.158-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- mypackage.integration:integration-bpm:jar:4.4.1.158-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- mypackage.integration:integration-http:jar:4.4.1.158-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-api:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  +- org.codehaus.woodstox:woodstox-core-asl:jar:4.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  |  \- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:3.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  +- org.apache.ws.xmlschema:xmlschema-core:jar:2.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  \- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-core:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:jar:2.0-m10:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-bindings-xml:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-http:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- xalan:serializer:jar:2.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.9.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:3.6.10.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:3.2.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:3.6.10.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javassist:javassist:jar:3.12.0.GA:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] +- mypackage.integration:integration-core:jar:4.4.1.158-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.safehaus.jug:jug:jar:asl:2.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.sf.dozer:dozer:jar:5.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.8.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.sf.json-lib:json-lib:jar:jdk15:2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- net.sf.ezmorph:ezmorph:jar:1.0.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- xom:xom:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- xerces:xmlParserAPIs:jar:2.6.2:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- jaxen:jaxen:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.aspectj:aspectjtools:jar:1.5.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- cglib:cglib:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- gov.hhs.healthit.nhin.connect:common-types:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj:saaj-impl:jar:1.3.19:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.jvnet.mimepull:mimepull:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] +- mypackage.integration:integration-test:jar:4.4.1.158-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- xmlunit:xmlunit:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  \- eviware:maven-soapui-plugin:jar:4.5.1:test
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0:test
[INFO] |     +- eviware:soapui:jar:4.5.1:test
[INFO] |     +- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |     +- wsdl4j:wsdl4j:jar:1.6.2-fixed:compile
[INFO] |     +- commons-ssl:not-yet-commons-ssl:jar:0.3.11:test
[INFO] |     +- commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.0:test
[INFO] |     +- json:json-lib:jar:2.2.2-jdk15:test
[INFO] |     +- ezmorph:ezmorph:jar:1.0.5:test
[INFO] |     +- swingx:swingx:jar:soapui:test
[INFO] |     +- groovy:groovy-all:jar:1.8.0:test
[INFO] |     +- rhino:js:jar:1.7R2:test
[INFO] |     +- jetty:jetty:jar:6.1.26:test
[INFO] |     +- jetty:jetty-util:jar:6.1.26:test
[INFO] |     +- jetty:servlet-api:jar:2.5-20081211:test
[INFO] |     +- net-components:netcomponents:jar:1.3.8a:test
[INFO] |     +- xmlbeans:xbean:jar:fixed-2.4.0:test
[INFO] |     +- xmlbeans:xbean_xpath:jar:2.4.0:test
[INFO] |     +- xmlbeans:xmlpublic:jar:2.4.0:test
[INFO] |     +- xmlbeans:jsr173:jar:xmlbeans-2.4.0:test
[INFO] |     +- eviware:soapui-xmlbeans:jar:4.5.1:test
[INFO] |     +- eviware:policy-xmlbeans:jar:1.5:test
[INFO] |     +- eviware:soap-xmlbeans:jar:1.2:test
[INFO] |     +- eviware:wadl-xmlbeans:jar:1.1:test
[INFO] |     +- eviware:j2ee-xmlbeans:jar:1.4:test
[INFO] |     +- eviware:ext-xmlbeans:jar:1.2:test
[INFO] |     +- saxon:saxon:jar:9.1.0.8j:test
[INFO] |     +- saxon:saxon-dom:jar:9.1.0.8j:test
[INFO] |     +- xml-security:xmlsec:jar:1.4.3:test
[INFO] |     +- opensaml:opensaml:jar:1.1:test
[INFO] |     +- wss4j:wss4j:jar:1.5.8:test
[INFO] |     +- bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15:jar:144:test
[INFO] |     +- jtidy:jtidy:jar:r872-jdk15:test
[INFO] |     +- javax.jms:jms:jar:1.1:test
[INFO] |     +- hermesjms:hermes:jar:1.14:test
[INFO] |     +- amf:flex-messaging-common:jar:1.0:test
[INFO] |     +- amf:flex-messaging-core:jar:1.0:test
[INFO] |     +- amf:flex-messaging-opt:jar:1.0:test
[INFO] |     +- amf:flex-messaging-proxy:jar:1.0:test
[INFO] |     +- amf:flex-messaging-remoting:jar:1.0:test
[INFO] |     +- thoughtworks:xstream:jar:1.3.1:test
[INFO] |     +- net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:jar:2.7:test
[INFO] |     |  \- commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.w3c.css:sac:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |     +- net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit-core-js:jar:2.7:test
[INFO] |     +- net.sourceforge.cssparser:cssparser:jar:0.9.5:test
[INFO] |     +- net.sourceforge.nekohtml:nekohtml:jar:1.9.14:test
[INFO] |     +- fife:rsyntaxtextarea:jar:1.3.4:test
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.1.1:test
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:jar:4.1.1:test
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-cache:jar:4.1.1:test
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.1.1:test
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore-nio:jar:4.1.1:test
[INFO] |     \- org.samba.jcifs:jcifs:jar:1.2.9:test
[INFO] +- mypackage.myapp:myapp_common:jar:4.4.1.158-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- mypackage.integration:integration-jms:jar:4.4.1.158-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- ca.uhn.hapi:hapi-base:jar:0.6:compile
[INFO] |  \- mypackage.integration:integration-feed:jar:4.4.1.158-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- mypackage.myapp:myapp_mock:jar:4.4.1.158-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- mypackage.integration:integration-hl7:jar:4.4.1.158-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- mypackage.myapp:myapp_bindings:jar:4.4.1.158-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  \- mypackage.myapp:myapp_audit:jar:4.4.1.158-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-asm:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-jms:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.1.0.RC2:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.ws:spring-ws:jar:2.0.0-M1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-oxm:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- asm:asm:jar:3.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-client:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-json:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jettison:jettison:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- stax:stax-api:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.2.3-1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- javax.xml.stream:stax-api:jar:1.0-2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-jaxrs:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-xc:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.sun.jersey.contribs:jersey-atom-abdera:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.abdera:abdera-parser:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.abdera:abdera-core:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.abdera:abdera-i18n:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-activation_1.0.2_spec:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-impl:jar:1.2.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-api:jar:1.2.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.codehaus.woodstox:wstx-asl:jar:3.2.6:runtime
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.abdera:abdera-extensions-json:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.abdera:abdera-server:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.abdera:abdera-extensions-main:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- org.apache.abdera:abdera-client:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.apache.abdera:abdera-extensions-html:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |        \- nu.validator.htmlparser:htmlparser:jar:1.0.5:compile
[INFO] +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-atom:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- rome:rome:jar:0.9:compile
[INFO] |  \- jdom:jdom:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.sun.jersey.contribs:jersey-multipart:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.jvnet:mimepull:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] +- com.sun.jersey.contribs:jersey-spring:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] +- com.sun.jersey.contribs:jersey-guice:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.inject:guice:jar:3.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.google.inject.extensions:guice-servlet:jar:3.0:compile
[INFO] +- net.sf.saxon:saxon:jar:9.1.0.8:compile
[INFO] +- net.sf.saxon:saxon-dom:jar:9.1.0.8:compile
[INFO] +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:provided
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:com.springsource.slf4j.org.apache.commons.logging:jar:1.6.1:runtime
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:com.springsource.slf4j.log4j:jar:1.6.1:runtime
[INFO] +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.16:compile
[INFO] +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:jar:7.6.13.v20130916:test
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty.orbit:javax.servlet:jar:2.5.0.v201103041518:test
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-continuation:jar:7.6.13.v20130916:test
[INFO] |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:jar:7.6.13.v20130916:test
[INFO] |     \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:jar:7.6.13.v20130916:test
[INFO] |        \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:7.6.13.v20130916:test
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.8.2:test
[INFO] +- com.oracle:ojdbc6:jar:11.1.0.6.0:test
[INFO] \- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:test
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I tried different things to get this to work and got it working, as specified here: [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/cxf/jaxrs/impl/UriBuilderImpl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25754850/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-cxf-jaxrs-impl-uribuilderimpl).  I think the main thing may have been to upgrade the version of Jersey and prefer it from the application packages.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with the same exception and message. We were using a mocking service that returned canned XML for matched requests. The problem was that the SOAP Body element had whitespace around its child and that triggered this exception.

Usually normal webservices generate one line XML that is consumed without any problems.

Comment: this was the exact issue, the mock service in the SOAPUI had spaces and after removing the spaces and made them as single line , it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

OK... I had the exactly same problem and solved it.
It's actually workaround.
Create your Envelope.class and Body.class, for example:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Envelope", namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")
public class Envelope {

    @XmlElement(name = "Body", namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")
    private Body body;

    public Body getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    public void setBody() {
        this.body = new Body();
    }

}
```

and

```
@XmlType
public class Body {

    @XmlElement(name = "NameOfElementChildInBody", namespace = "namespace if needed for body")
    private POJOClassOfElementChildInBody someVariableName;

    public void setterIfNeeded(POJOClassOfElementChildInBody someVariableName) {
        this.someVariableName = someVariableName;
    }

}
```

and in your code put:

```
SOAPMessage response = dispatch.invoke(request);

ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
response.writeTo(out);

JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Envelope.class);
Unmarshaller um = jc.createUnmarshaller();

Envelope envelope = (Envelope) um.unmarshal(new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray()));
Body body = envelope.getBody();
body.methodFromWsdl... etc.
```