# WebLogic + odata4j = java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/cxf/jaxrs/impl/UriBuilderImpl

Tags: java, weblogic

I have web application with some legacy code written with odata4j running at WebLogic 12.1.2.0 and Java 1.7. Sometimes (but not always) when i try to get metadata from my OData service i have exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/cxf/jaxrs/impl/UriBuilderImpl.

Full stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/cxf/jaxrs/impl/UriBuilderImpl
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.RuntimeDelegateImpl.createUriBuilder(RuntimeDelegateImpl.java:87)
    at javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.newInstance(UriBuilder.java:69)
    at javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.fromUri(UriBuilder.java:80)
    at javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.fromUri(UriBuilder.java:99)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:649)
    at weblogic.jaxrs.server.portable.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:218)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:844)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:341)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    at org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationPropagationFilter.doFilter(ConversationPropagationFilter.java:62)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3367)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3333)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2220)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2146)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2124)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1564)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:254)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:295)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:254)
```

I've tried to examine this class via wls-cat and have this results:

```
General Information
Type: weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader
HashCode: 1492139542

Resource Analysis
Resource: org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.UriBuilderImpl
Checksum: 3c9f3e5e3c2493e3d960c4e0cb41ed97
Load Location:     jar:file:/home/stas/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/user_projects/domains/xxx/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/datagrid/9s8vqk/war/WEB-INF/lib/cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-2.6.0.jar!/org/apache/cxf/jaxrs/impl/UriBuilderImpl.class
Classloader Type: weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader
Classloader Hash Code: 1492139542
Classloader Search Order: 1492139542 ->1492139542

Alternative Locations:

/home/stas/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/user_projects/domains/xxx/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/datagrid/9s8vqk/war/WEB-INF/lib/cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-2.6.0.jar!/org/apache/cxf/jaxrs/impl/UriBuilderImpl.class
/home/stas/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/user_projects/domains/xxx/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/datagrid/9s8vqk/war/WEB-INF/lib/odata4j-dist-0.7.0.jar!/org/apache/cxf/jaxrs/impl/UriBuilderImpl.class
```

and this claas is present in loaded classes list.

I don't have any idea how this problem can be solved, so, any help welcome.

Comment: possible duplicate of [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/cxf/jaxrs/impl/UriBuilderImpl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25754850/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-cxf-jaxrs-impl-uribuilderimpl)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this mvn configuration of odata4j helps with problem:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.odata4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>odata4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>0.7.0</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```